# Cannot get simplest Phoenix lambda to compile

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I am currently trying to get the following very simple `boost::phoenix::lambda` to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/phoenix/scope.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::phoenix::lambda[std::cout << "Lambda!!"]();
}
```

However, this generates a host of errors (too much to post here), none which make any sense to me. Here is an excerpt of the compiler output:

```
error: 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private 
       within this context
error: initializer for 
       'boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, 
        boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::vector0<> >, 0l>::proto_child0 
        {aka boost::phoenix::vector0<>}' must be brace-enclosed
```

I am compiling these using MinGW 4.7.2 on Windows XP with Boost 1.53.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not familiar with Boost::Phoenix but in c++11, you'd write: `[] () { std::cout << "Lambda!!"; }`

Comment: The expression inside the square brackets is evaluated, and then the lambda tries to copy the returned `std::ostream` object, which it can't, because iostreams are non-copyable. Did you think that wrapping an expression in `phoenix::lambda[...]` would magically make it lazy?

Comment: @Xeo that should be an answer not a comment

Comment: Try `boost::phoenix::lambda[boost::phoenix::ref(std::cout) << "Lambda!!"]()();` for which you you need `boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp`. If the double `()()` surprises you then do not start using `boost::phoenix::lambda` before knowing the basics, of which `lambda` is not.

Comment: @LucDanton: Make it an answer.

Comment: @Xeo: I guess I was mislead by the fact that the [documentation for `boost::phoenix::let`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/scope/let.html) uses a very similar example. I had a problem and though `lets use lambda`, and then I had two problems...

Comment: @BjörnPollex: `let` uses special placeholders that kick off expression-template generation and all that stuff.

Answer (score 4):

**Firstly**, always

```
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
```

unless you know what you're doing.

**Secondly**, you need to make either operand of `operator<<` be a phoenix terminal, otherwise, it will be just

```
std::cout << "Lambda!!"
```

which is an expression of type `std::ostream&`...

Now, you could do anything, really, e.g.

```
phx::ref(std::cout) << "Lambda!!"
```

or

```
std::cout << phx::val("Lambda!!")
```

Either will compile.